# What to consider when adding a new web store to Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

Our company has 2 websites, but now there is another one on Prestashop that we bought and we want to have all 3 webstores in our one Magento admin but all on separate domains. I'm a bit confused about whether it is possible.
I mean.. We create a new webstore in Magento admin. How can we match this new store with this Prestashop store's domain? Then we were thinking of extracting all products from Prestashop to a XML file and import it to Magento.

Could there be any difficulties involving these procedures that I cannot think of right now..?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned **Magento 1.9** in the question tag, I would like to tell that, Magento has announced the end of support date for **Magento 1.x** versions. So it would be better to go with **Magento 2.x** version.

Next, Magento can handle multiple websites on different domains from a single admin panel.

You just need to create multi-store setup and configure each store's base URL individually.

You also need to map the domains to point to different URLs.

**Next Concern:** Could there be any difficulties involving these procedures that I cannot think of right now..?

**Reply:** Yes, there may be some points you should consider:

- You need to migrate product categories and attributes.
- Before migrating the products, you would need to convert PrestaShop products XML to Magento's readable format.
- While migrating customers, you may lose the passwords since both platforms have the different format to save the users' password.
- To migrate orders, invoices etc. you need to either write custom code or take help of some paid modules.